# How to add your own rand_poll implementation in openssl?

Tags: c++, random, openssl, win-universal-app

I'm working on porting openssl library to uwp(Universal Windows 10 Platform). The standard rand_poll implementation doesn't seem to work for uwp. I'm thinking adding a customized implementation. For this, i have created a .cpp file(the support for namespace is not present in C, so i had  to add a cpp file), which contains my customized implementation of rand_poll(). How do i add this file to the openssl build system so as to use rand_poll functionality from my file rather than from rand_win.c?

Any pointers and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to prevent the original implementation from being linked into your project.  For that you can use conditional compilation, e.g. in rand_win.c:

```
#if ! UWP # or some other way to detect UWP
...original RAND_poll implementation...
#endif
```

Then in your .cpp file:

```
extern "C" int RAND_poll(void)
{
// your impl
}
```

The `extern "C"` bit is required to make the compiler export this symbol as a C-callable function, without C++ name mangling.  You can use C++ code in the implementation.  Just don't let any C++ exceptions escape your function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is very helpful. I had one doubt though. How do i add my file to the OpenSSL build system?

Comment: @salman1864830: Do a search for `rand_win.c` and I guess you'll find the appropriate makefile or other config file where you need to add your .cpp file.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about this? I think just replacing the c file with cpp file won't work out(In uwp, cpp files are compiled with /ZW flag. The c files won't compile if you specify this flag)

Answer (score 0):

> For this, i have created a .cpp file(the support for namespace is not present in C, so i had to add a cpp file), which contains my customized implementation of rand_poll().

You should avoid `rand_poll` altogether. See [Random Numbers | Windows Issues](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Windows_Issues) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Instead, you should:

```
IBuffer buffer = CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(length);
```

And then pass the buffer to OpenSSL's `RAND_seed`.

---

> How do i add this file to the openssl build system so as to use rand_poll functionality from my file rather than from rand_win.c?

Its probably easiest to whip up a patch and replace it in-place. You can find the source in `<openssl dir>/crypto/rand/rand_win.c`.

Or, create an ENGINE, and then replace the default random methods with your engine's methods. An easy to follow example is Intel's RDRAND engine. Here are the files of interest when adding a similar engine:

```
$ grep -IR _rdrand * | cut -f 1 -d ':' | sort | uniq
crypto/engine/Makefile
crypto/engine/eng_all.c
crypto/engine/eng_rdrand.c
crypto/engine/engine.h
crypto/x86_64cpuid.pl
crypto/x86cpuid.pl
include/openssl/engine.h
...
```

Comment: The way c files and cpp files are compiled for uwp are different. Just patching up and replacing it in-place doesn't work.